# Run function multiple times without updating over previous result python

Tags: python, pandas, twitter, tweepy

I am working with the twitter API and wrote the following function:

```
import tweepy
import pandas as pd
import traceback
import datetime

def tweets(username, count):
    
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    data = {}

    try:
        for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline,id=username).items(count):
            
            timesince = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - tweet.created_at #calculate the time since tweet was posted
            ipm = (tweet.favorite_count + tweet.retweet_count) / (abs(int(timesince.total_seconds() / 60))) #interactions per minute

            data['retweets'] = tweet.retweet_count
            data['favorites'] = tweet.favorite_count
            data['total_interactions'] = tweet.favorite_count + tweet.retweet_count
            data['ipm'] = ipm #interactions per minute
            
            df = df.append(data, ignore_index=True)
            
        return df
    except tweepy.RateLimitError:
        print("Rate limit exceeded")
    except tweepy.TweepError as err:
        print("Error: %s" % err.reason)
    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()
```

The idea is to run this function multiple times and create a log for interactions per minute. The current output of this function is a dataframe with the 4 columns as defined within the function. However, I want the interactions per minute column to add the new IPM value (like creating a list of the IPM for each tweet every time the function is run) every time I run the function instead of just updating over the old value. I tried creating a global variable and appending to that so every time the function is ran, the data isn't lost but that isn't working as it is being treated as different tweets rather than an update of an already collected tweet. Soo any ideas? Any help is appreciated! I figure this is more of a python problem rather than a twitter API issue

Comment: Hi, I would appreciate that very much. Deleted it because it was pointed out to me I didn't tag the question properly. Is there a way I can DM you?

Comment: Undeleted it, here is the link if you need it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72413019/comparing-two-sets-of-probabilities-to-see-which-one-is-a-better-predictor-of-th?noredirect=1#comment127923473_72413019

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data.clear()` once the data has been displayed or saved, use the function `.clear()` to empty the list for fresh data to override it.

Thanks!

Comment: Apologies if I misunderstood but I would like to add on to the data collected from the previous run of the function. So for example I run it once for one tweet and in the IPM column the value is 5. When I run it a second time, I would like the output to be [5, x] - where x is the updated value of IPM. So instead of x replacing 5, i would like to add it alongside 5

Comment: Is the data being placed in data or df?

Comment: This is part of a larger function where in the end, the data will be placed in both ```df``` and ```data```