# Comparing two sets of probabilities to see which one is a better predictor of the outcome

Tags: python, pandas, probability, confusion-matrix, hypothesis-test

Suppose there are two columns of the probability that the home team wins a given match and then a column at the end indicating whether the home team won or not. Looking like this:

```
 prob_1    prob_2       WinHomeTeam
  0.495     0.541           1
  0.490     0.539           0
  0.485     0.483           1
  0.377     0.392           0
  0.543     0.532           1
  0.530     0.545           1
```

Assuming the 3 columns is all the information we have and this data is part of a much bigger dataset, what would be the best way to determine which column is a better predictor of the outcome?

The method I have tried so far is to create a confusion matrix and for my case, assume probability above 0.5 as a win. Then using the results from that, compare the probability columns. Are there any other better methods that I can use?

Comment: Please re-tag your question - It looks that you don't have any python or pandas issues. Your question is not even a programming question and should be asked in another stack exchange site.

Comment: @TDG Yes, we have to kill it with fire.

Answer (score 1):

Answering here from a programming point of view. If you need to discuss the best statistical method better ask on https://stats.stackexchange.com

I see two options, you can compute the fraction of correct guesses:

```
df.filter(like='prob').gt(0.5).astype(int).eq(df['WinHomeTeam'], axis=0).mean()
```

Output:

```
prob_1    0.666667
prob_2    0.666667
dtype: float64
```

Or compute the correlation between your guesses and the truth:

```
from sklearn.metrics import matthews_corrcoef

df.filter(like='prob').gt(0.5).corrwith(df['WinHomeTeam'], method=matthews_corrcoef)
```

Output:

```
prob_1    0.50
prob_2    0.25
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I was looking for a programmatic answer anyway. A theoretical answer would have been fine but then I would just have searched around for how to translate that into python anyways. So thanks for your help, I will try this out and delete this post as it is in the wrong place seemingly.

Comment: @sak what you can do is find first the best method, then improve/update your question so that it benefits to everyone;)